# Dual booting Fedora and Windows, but BIOS only detects Windows

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, bios

I am helping someone dual boot Fedora on an MSI motherboard build. They had Windows 10, and we have shrunk the Windows partition and installed Fedora in the free space (drive was 2TB, Fedora now has 1TB). It installed successfully, but we can only get it to boot (instead of Windows) by spamming F11 and choosing it from the one-time boot menu, after which GRUB 2 loads normally. The BIOS only shows Windows on the one SSD in the boot priority list. How can we fix this so it boots to GRUB by default?

Comment: is secure boot enabled in BIOS? what about CSM? Did you install Fedora EFI boot capable?

Comment: @JaromandaX I will check for secure boot and CSM in BIOS, but what do you mean “EFI boot capable”? We downloaded the iso and flashed it to disk using Rufus.

Comment: I don't know fedora to answer that

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred I’m sorry, *what?*

Comment: Click on the link & follow the directions. Then post link to the Summary Report it creates so we can see the details of your install.

Comment: I have a potential other solution that’s basically just how to actually use the bios and change the boot priority (I’m unfamiliar with MSI), but if that doesn’t work, I’ll try those links you sent. Thanks.